# Default Apex application on Tomcat 7.0.41

Tags: tomcat, tomcat7, oracle-apex

I'm running Oracle Application Express 4.1 on Tomcat 7.0.41.

Basically, I'm trying to find a way to go directly to my apex application using hostname:port. With the default apex install, you have to do this by navigating to hostname:port/apex/f?p=111, where 111 is the number of the apex application. 
I made apex the default application in tomcat, so now navigating to hostname:port gets me to the apex login page. Going to hostname:port/f?p=111 will now get me to my app.
However, what I really want to do is to get to my application by just typing in hostname:port. I'm trying to avoid doing a meta refresh to the full url.
 Is there any way to do this?

Comment: If Apex requires you to go to `/f?p=111`, then you'll have to get the user there somehow. What's wrong with going to the login page?

Comment: @Christopher Schultz There's nothing wrong with it, per se. It's just the login for the development environment, which the normal app user won't need. I was hoping that Tomcat allowed you to specify a URL to display as the default web page, and that way a normal user could just go to hostname:port and be right at the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that there is no way to do this, after a few more days of research. I'll be using a `<meta refresh>` in the default Tomcat webpage to get me to my application.